# Переопределение (override) невиртуального метода

Tags: c++, классы, функции

Я не совсем понимаю, что происходит в следующем случае:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    void f()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    int b;
    void f()
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Эксперименты показали, что `B::f()` перекрывает `A::f()`, в результате чего достучаться до `A::f()` уже нельзя. Я хочу понять, как это работает на уровне языка, и зачем так вообще делают.

Comment: До `A::f` достучаться можно без проблем. `override` здесь отсутствует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достучаться до `A::f()` вполне можно. Например,

```
B b;
b.A::f();
```

или

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
    int b;
    void f()
    {
        A::f();
    }
};
```

Как сделано? элементарно - тип вызывающего объекта известен? известен. Значит, вызываем `f()`, прописанную в этом типе, определяя адрес во время компиляции. В отличие от виртуальной функции, адрес которой вычисляется во время выполнения.

Зачем? Не знаю, для меня вопрос странный... А зачем бы - нет?

К чему использовать механизм поиска в vtbl там, где он не нужен? :)